# Preventing MC from leaving stage with bounding rectangle AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, drag-and-drop, bounding-box, animate-cc

I have tried many of the suggestions in other posts but cannot get this working fully.

I would like to drag an object around my stage, but I don't want that object to actually leave the stage.

When using the example below, the MC is bound by the top and bottom of the stage, but the left side still swallows up half of the dragged MC, and the right side doesn't allow the MC to get near the edge - it just has blank space (by what looks like the same width that the MC gets dragged outside on the left)

```
var my_x:int=stage.stageWidth-box_mc.width;
var my_y:int=stage.stageHeight-box_mc.height;

var myWidth:int=0-my_x;
var myHeight:int=0-my_y;

var boundArea:Rectangle=new Rectangle(my_x, my_y, myWidth, myHeight);

box_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, drag);
box_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, drop);

function drag(event:MouseEvent):void {
    box_mc.startDrag(false,boundArea);
}

function drop(event:MouseEvent):void {
    box_mc.stopDrag();
}
```

I believe the code is correct, and there must be something I am missing - can someone try this out for me please and point me in the right direction?

Many Thanks,

Chris.

Comment: Top left corner of the stage is normally (0,0), thus your area rectangle should be **(0, 0, stage.stageWidth - box_mc.width, stage.stageHeight - box_mc.height)** rather than negative to 0 as you have it now.

Comment: Thanks Organis, although the way I read your solution to me seems like the way I already have it set up. Can you clarify please?

Comment: Trace your rectangle. Your top left is at the right bottom, while width and height are **negative**. Although in general terms it is the same rectangle area, mathematically speaking it is not.

Comment: Thanks Organis. I have got it working by tweaking your example (and doing a bit of extra trimming) - but this still doesn't look right to me. Could you take a look at the below please and let me know where i'm going wrong?

Comment: var boundArea:Rectangle=new Rectangle(+86, 0, stage.stageWidth - 
    box_mc.width, stage.stageHeight - box_mc.height);

    box_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, drag);
    box_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, drop);

    function drag(event:MouseEvent):void {
       box_mc.startDrag(false,boundArea);
    }

    function drop(event:MouseEvent):void {
        box_mc.stopDrag();
    }

Comment: _Not right_ how?

Comment: I had to +86 pixels to get the whole box bound?

Comment: So? You shifted the whole rectangle 86 pixels to the right. If you wanted to shift just the left border, you should've reduced the width accordingly. You might also want to preview your rectangle area, you can do that with **graphics.lineStyle(...)** and **graphics.drawRect(...)** methods: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html

Comment: So = because I had to shift the whole rectangle 86 pixels to the right, that is the problem - I shouldn't have to do this in a blank .fla with only box_mc in it if the corner of the stage is 0,0. The original code I posted should know the corner of the stage is 0,0 and also pick up the starting coordinates of box_mc!

Comment: @frltd - where is the anchor point in box_mc?  Top left corner?  the middle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your registration point is to blame for the behaviour you're experiencing.

You should use something like:

```
var boxArea:Rectangle = box_mc.getBounds(box_mc);
var boundArea:Rectangle = new Rectangle(-boxArea.x, -boxArea.y, stage.stageWidth-boxArea.width, stage.stageHeight-boxArea.height);

box_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, drag);
box_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, drop);

function drag(event:MouseEvent):void {
    box_mc.startDrag(false,boundArea);
}

function drop(event:MouseEvent):void {
   box_mc.stopDrag();
}
```

Basically, in the code above, you get the rectangle size of the **box_mc** object and deposit it in the **boxArea** variable and make sure to include its size and the registration point effects to the **boundArea** calculation.

Comment: Perfect thankyou so much, I now understand what I was doing wrong!